# Android google map Fragment error

Tags: android, google-maps

I use this guide: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/

But it does not work, I have registered API Key in google console, and add in the manifest, I add in manifest permission.

this is MapsActivity:

```
package aimprogman.mustwork;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
  }
}
```

this is activity_maps.xml

```
  <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

But it does not work and show error:

```
08-29 10:51:01.767 15491-15491/aimprogman.mustwork E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: aimprogman.mustwork, PID: 15491
                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{aimprogman.mustwork/aimprogman.mustwork.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2658)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                                     at
```

Comment: Problem is in your xml file. Please add this line and try <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: @JRamesh i add this line but not work, it's not resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry,i missed add

```
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

It is work fine, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your xml use the below code

```
 <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

In your activity initiate as below in OnCreate -

```
 mMapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
```

This is also a way of initializing map and it works better on all devices.

If you still want to use map fragment for your map please show me your manifest so i can see if you have missed out something there.

Comment: Thank i missed  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>